# Function in C++ to read the console if there is data and if not continue execution?

Tags: c++, input, console, cin

I was wondering if there is a function in C++ that can retrieve data that was given   in the console, and if there is not, do not pause in the cin and continue the program execution.

Thanks

Comment: So when exactly will the user give input if it doesn't pause?

Comment: Your title makes sense.  Asking about a "special type of `cin`" does not.  The type of `cin` is `std::istream`, according to section 27.4.2 of the Standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard function to do this in C++, and exactly how you do it in a "non-standard" way depends on the OS that the code is to run on.

One solution is to use a special "handle console/keyboard I/O" library. An example of that is the "curses" library, which is available in one flavour or another for most popular platforms. If you are on a Linux or Unix platform, try using the software installer product (yum, apt-get, etc) to search for "curses". If you are on Windows, there's no generic "install code to do ", so you have to use google to search for "curses for windows".

Comment: Or there is a function that can check if the input buffer has some data, so I can put the cin instruction inside an if? The program is generating data that sends it to a server X period of time but also needs to obtain data from user. One option was to divide the actions into thread but I do not know much of the topic.

Comment: There is no such thing as "check if someone has typed something" or similar in the C++ standard. If you want to "check if someone has pressed a key" or something along those lines, you CAN NOT use just standard C++ code. In `cin`, the data in the keyboard buffer [or whatever `cin` is reading it's data from] is not actually available to `cin` until it has been read, and `cin` uses a "blocking read", which means that it's going to "stop" if there is no data available. This is to allow C++ to be implemented on "any" type of system.

Comment: Why not write two threads and have one monitor the console input?

Comment: @PurpleAlien has a decent suggestion. It all depends on what the actual goal is, but for most things, that would definitely work.

Answer (score 2):

Have two threads, one blocks waiting for input and the other does work while waiting.